# Not able to get correct difference between two dates using joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to get the difference between the two dates using joda time, but somehow I am not able to get the exact difference.

```
        LocalDate endofCentury = new LocalDate(2014, 01, 01);

        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); //2017-04-11

        Period diff = new Period(endofCentury, now); 

        System.out.printf("Difference is %d years, %d months and %d days old", 
                            diff.getYears(), diff.getMonths(), diff.getDays());
```

The difference should come as **3 years, 3 months, 10 days** but I am getting **3 years, 3 months and 3 days**.

Not sure what I am missing, please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constructor with 3 parameters:

`Period diff = new Period(endofCentury, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());`

The constructor with 2 parameters `(from,to)` includes weeks.

So a modified output of your code:

```
Period diff = new Period(endofCentury, now);
System.out.printf("Difference is %d years, %d months and %d weeks and %d days old",
                diff.getYears(), diff.getMonths(),diff.getWeeks(), diff.getDays());
```

gives the output:

> Difference is 3 years, 3 months and 1 weeks and 3 days old

but with specified duration fields (3rd parameter):

```
Period diff = new Period(endofCentury, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
System.out.printf("Difference is %d years, %d months and %d weeks and %d days old",
            diff.getYears(), diff.getMonths(),diff.getWeeks(), diff.getDays());
```

you get:

> Difference is 3 years, 3 months and 0 weeks and 10 days old

see: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html

Comment: Thanks @Jérôme. The solution worked for me.